# How can pass a struct through multiple namespaces without 'using' them?

Tags: c#

This is kind of a simple problem (or maybe not) which I'm caught up on. I have an application TestApp which uses a UI library that I'm working on which in turn uses a graphics library (SharpDX).

Now SharpDX provides a Color struct (SharpDX.Color). And my Window class (UI.Window) accepts a SharpDX.Color struct to clear the rendertarget.

However, when using the UI library, the SharpDX namespace isn't available. But this causes the problem that Color isn't available.

So is it possible to make Color available in the UI namespace, avoiding the need to also have references to SharpDX in the project that uses the UI library.

Thanks.

Comment: Not directly. But you can add a new struct to the UI library which you use in the public interface, and internally translate it to the SharpDX struct in the implementation of the UI library.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for getting onto this so quickly, So I either make it clear that SharpDX namespace needs to be included when using my UI library, or I just make my own UI.Color struct and translate it. I think making the compatible struct is the better way to go, just for ease of use and clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, to use part of a library, you need to use the entire library (unless the author has broken it down into submodules).

If you are using the UI library, how can you pass it a SharpDX.Color without also using SharpDX?
If you only wish to use part of your library you can split off the components which depend on SharpDX from the rest.

Alternatively, you can make your own Color struct, and translate between UI.Color and SharpDX.Color at the intersection between UI and SharpDX code.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is separate the colour struct into a common library or you can map the colour struct to a new struct provided by the UI library.

If this is not possible to edit the code of SharpDX (3rd party?) then you can reference it in both projects or map it to a new struct in the UI library